# ghc.EXE: addDLL: icuuc59.dll (Win32 error 126): The specified module could not be found

Tags: windows, haskell, dll, static-linking

So I've done this a year ago but I forgot what's the trick Googling didn't help.
As I understand it, the problem is that I need to statically link my dlls. 
I'm doing this on WINDOWS

I did `stack install text-icu --extra-include-dirs=C:\icu4c-59_1-Win64-MSVC2015\include --extra-lib-dirs=C:\icu4c-59_1-Win64-MSVC2015\lib64`

and I tried putting the dll into my .stack-work\install\28cbf0ed\bin folder but when I try stack build I get

```
ghc.EXE: unable to load package `text-icu-0.7.0.1'
ghc.EXE: addDLL: icuuc59.dll (Win32 error 126): The specified module could not be found.
ghc.EXE: Could not load `icuuc59.dll'. Reason: addDLL: could not load DLL
```

I suppose I should be putting the dlls somewhere else or something